# SQL- Executing simple query within netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans, syntax, derby

I'm new to SQL and I am also new to NetBeans. So please forgive me if this is really simple, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have a table called "user" which has the columns "id", "username", and "password". I'm trying to retrieve a single row from my database. The only fields I need are the username and password. So I have the following:

```
    SELECT 
    user.username AS "Username",
    user.password AS "Password"
    FROM "user"
    WHERE
    user.username = "billy"
```

I'm using netbeans to test my query. I have setup a database that contains a user with the username "billy" along with a corresponding password. When I click "Run SQL" within netbeans, it comes back with the following error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: java.lang.String.username.
Line 1, column 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after a bit of trial and error, I replaced all of the references to `user.column` with `"column"`. That seemed to solve my problem. For reference, here's what the query looks like:

```
    SELECT 
    "username" AS "Username", 
    "password" AS "Password" 
    FROM "user" 
    WHERE 
    "username" = 'Billy'
```